# Stored procedure : how to insert the relational data?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How to insert the inserted value id into another tables in same function of stored procedure?

For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p1(IN id_val INT, IN name_val VARCHAR(255))
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @iJobID [INT]
    SET @iJobID=(INSERT INTO test(id, name) VALUES(id_val, name_val));
    INSERT INTO vasu(id) VALUES(@iJobID); 
END;
```

Comment: So what's your question? Is this not working?

Comment: No its not working, can you give me an examples for same

Comment: *How* is it not working? what does the error message tell you?

Comment: hi Rowland, this is the error message i'm getting::: (Stored procedure creation failed: (1064) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@iJobID [INT] SET @iJobID=(INSERT INTO test(id, name) VALUES(id_val, name_va' at line 3CALL failed: (1305) PROCEDURE jv_phpclasses.p1 does not exist)

Comment: what do you want to get on this line? `SET @iJobID=(INSERT INTO test(id, name) VALUES(id_val, name_val));`

Comment: Hi JW i want inserted id which will get after row is insert, this is i need to insert into another table

Comment: is there an AUTO_INCREMENTed column which contains your Primary Key ID?

Comment: yes, ID is auto incremented so i need that value to updatd in another table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get the last inserted ID and set it on the local variable.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE p1 
(
    IN id_val INT, 
    IN name_val VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO test(id, name) VALUES(id_val, name_val);
    SET @iJobID :=  LAST_INSERT_ID();
    INSERT INTO vasu(id) VALUES(@iJobID); 

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

- [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Comment: Hi JW its Inserting "0" value INSERT INTO vasu(id) VALUES(@iJobID);

Comment: can you show the result of this query `DESC test`, this will display the structure of the table `test`

Comment: Here is the Structure of table "test":
id int(11) primary key
name varchar(255)

Comment: why do you set a value on this column `id` with `id_val`? and your `ID` column isn't set as `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

Comment: to work it normally, first `ID` should be set as `AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY`, then on the insert statement it should only be `INSERT INTO test(name) VALUES(name_val);`

Comment: No its id is AUTO_INCREMENT i forgot to mention in above comment

Comment: here is the table structure of "test" for above query "
1 id int(11) No None AUTO_INCREMENT
2 name varchar(255)"

Comment: @ObjectInvisible what did you do? you said it was already autoincremented?

Comment: yes, there is the issue with the primary key now it is fixed thanks again @JW